# AR Scene Black Screen Issue in Android with AR Core AR Foundation and Niantic ARDK 3

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arkit, arcore, ar-foundation

My Unity Version is Unity 2021.3.30f1 and i have AR in my game and i have installed all the AR related packages into my Projectg including XR Managment AR Core AR Foundation AR Kit Niantic AR 3.3 and i am getting black screen when ever i just build and run it on my Android device i dont what is wrong i have changed the project settings acording to Niantic ARDK and AR Foundation but still doesn't work my Project is on Built in Render Pipline. Any help would be apritiated. Thanks in advance

I triend and went through all the Unity forms and stack overflow but didn't find any solution to work for me